# Force.com Toolkit for PHP - Still Officially Supported?

Tags: api, integration, php, wsdl

Looking at the current websites here:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit
- https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP

I wonder if the toolkit is still supported? Seems to me, that since 2010 no updates have been made. It's still on v20.0, however it seems to be possible to replace the wsdl and endpoint-url to use v31.0. I only tried a simple query, but at least got some promising results.

Is it still recommended to use it? Or is there something else to access Salesforce via php?
Anyone got more experience with it? Is it reliable with wsdl > v20.0?

Is this toolkit the right choice for php-based heroku projects to interact with salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need the new > v20.0 features, you can still use it verbatim for some time. It really isn't much more than a wrapper for things you'd do yourself if you used SoapClient (I've done this for a small Drupal module).

Of course, you can just drop a v31.0 WSDL in the appropriate place, and it should work just fine. I wouldn't just change the endpoint, I'd refresh the entire WSDL. I've not personally tested this, but I can't imagine any game changing features that'd break such a simple wrapper.

As for "recommended" practices, use the language that will get you where you want to go, whatever is most comfortable. Php, Ruby, and Java are all supported and have just about the same level of difficulty with using the WSDL.

Alternatively, you might consider not using the WSDL. REST is the new SOAP, and it lets you authenticate easily against an org without compromising user names or passwords, uses less bandwidth and memory, doesn't require WSDL binding, and basically just makes life easy. On the other hand, you do end up writing more code, but your overall code base will be far smaller.

There's no known flaws in the PHP toolkit, so there really hasn't been a need to update the code. Use it if you feel php is the right technology for your use case and skill set.